# can't call construtor SimpleCursorAdapter in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, simplecursoradapter

why i can't call SimpleCursorAdapter in Fragment project, this my code :

```
    private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE ,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DATE};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 ,R.id.date_row};

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.note_row, notesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
```

thanks, please help me, cause because I'm chasing deadline

Comment: What is the error? First thought that comes to mind is that you need to replace `this` with `getActivity()`. A fragment is not by itself a valid context, the context is provided by the underlying Activity.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Yeees its work, but i have error again with setListAdapter, error is " the methode setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter) is undefined for the type ReviewFragment" what should i do? Thanks before

Comment: Well, a bit hard to tell from the small amount of code, but sounds like you are extending `Fragment` but really meant to extend `ListFragment`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) is depricated in lvl 11. Use `SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)`. If you want develop application under lvl11 use

```
android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter
```

Comment: Thanks, now i have error again with setListAdapter, error is " the methode setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter) is undefined for the type ReviewFragment" what should i do? Thanks before

Comment: Your fragment must extend ListFragment. Probably your extend Fragment.